# Constant Contact : How to resolve error "JSON payload cannot be empty."

Tags: php, curl, constantcontact

I want to use API of the constant contact and want to insert user Email Ids using PHP script while user register to the website.

I using following code for this.

```
    $data['addresses'][0]['address_type'] = 'BUSINESS';
    $data['addresses'][0]['city'] = 'Belleville';
    $data['addresses'][0]['country_code'] = 'CA';
    $data['addresses'][0]['line1'] = '47 Shawmut Ave.';
    $data['addresses'][0]['line2'] = 'Suite 404';
    $data['addresses'][0]['postal_code'] = '"K8b 5W6';
    $data['addresses'][0]['state_code'] = 'ON';

    $data['lists'][0]['id'] = "1554397204";

    $data['cell_phone'] = "555-555-5555";
    $data['company_name'] = "System Optimzations";
    $data['confirmed'] = false;

    $data['email_addresses'][0]['email_address'] = "username112@example.com";

    $data['fax'] = "555-555-5555";
    $data['first_name'] = "Manvendra";
    $data['home_phone'] = "555-555-5555";
    $data['job_title'] = "Systems Analyst 3";
    $data['last_name'] = "Rajpurohit";
    $data['prefix_name'] = "Mr.Martone";
    $data['work_phone'] = "555-555-5555";
$jsonstring = json_encode($data);
    // echo '<pre>'; print_r($data);

$posturl = "https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/contacts?action_by=ACTION_BY_OWNER&api_key=*******";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $posturl);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $authstr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonstring);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json",'Authorization: Bearer *****
','Content-Length: ' . strlen($jsonstring)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // Do not return headers
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); // If you set this to 0, it will take you to a page with the http response

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (FALSE === $response)
throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
echo '<pre>'; print_r($response); die;
curl_close($ch);
```

When I run this script then its showing following error.

```
[{"error_key":"json.payload.empty","error_message":"JSON payload cannot be empty."}]
```

Please help me that how can I resolve this error.

Comment: Don't provide your secret info in your question. It will lead to you in future problems.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is validation error,which is:-

```
[{"error_key":"json.max.length.violation","error_message":"#/prefix_name: Value exceeds maximum length of 4."}]
```

So what i did is changed:-

```
$data['prefix_name'] = "Mr.Martone";
```

To:-

```
$data['prefix_name'] = "tone"; // length need to be 4 or less only
```

And used this CURL request and data saved successfully.

```
<?php

  $data['addresses'][0]['address_type'] = 'BUSINESS';
    $data['addresses'][0]['city'] = 'Belleville';
    $data['addresses'][0]['country_code'] = 'CA';
    $data['addresses'][0]['line1'] = '47 Shawmut Ave.';
    $data['addresses'][0]['line2'] = 'Suite 404';
    $data['addresses'][0]['postal_code'] = '"K8b 5W6';
    $data['addresses'][0]['state_code'] = 'ON';

    $data['lists'][0]['id'] = "1554397204";

    $data['cell_phone'] = "555-555-5555";
    $data['company_name'] = "System Optimzations";
    $data['confirmed'] = false;

    $data['email_addresses'][0]['email_address'] = "username112@example.com";

    $data['fax'] = "555-555-5555";
    $data['first_name'] = "Manvendra";
    $data['home_phone'] = "555-555-5555";
    $data['job_title'] = "Systems Analyst 3";
    $data['last_name'] = "Rajpurohit";
    $data['prefix_name'] = "tone";
    $data['work_phone'] = "555-555-5555";
$jsonstring = json_encode($data);
//echo '<pre>'; print_r($data);

$posturl = "https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/contacts?action_by=ACTION_BY_OWNER&api_key=*******";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $posturl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonstring);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json",'Authorization: Bearer ******')); //check change here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);// this need to be 1

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (FALSE === $response)
throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
echo '<pre>'; print_r($response); die;
curl_close($ch);
```

Output i got is:-

```
{
    "id": "1519826644",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "fax": "555-555-5555",
    "addresses": [{
        "id": "9ac8fd40-c2b2-11e7-aa57-d4ae5284344f",
        "line1": "47 Shawmut Ave.",
        "line2": "Suite 404",
        "line3": "",
        "city": "Belleville",
        "address_type": "BUSINESS",
        "state_code": "ON",
        "state": "Ontario",
        "country_code": "ca",
        "postal_code": "\"K8b",
        "sub_postal_code": "5W6"
    }],
    "notes": [],
    "confirmed": false,
    "lists": [{
        "id": "1554397204",
        "status": "ACTIVE"
    }],
    "source": "API",
    "email_addresses": [{
        "id": "9a914b70-c2b2-11e7-aa57-d4ae5284344f",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "confirm_status": "NO_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED",
        "opt_in_source": "ACTION_BY_OWNER",
        "opt_in_date": "2017-11-06T05:23:21.000Z",
        "email_address": "username23333@example.com"
    }],
    "prefix_name": "tone",
    "first_name": "Manvendra",
    "middle_name": "",
    "last_name": "Rajpurohit",
    "job_title": "Systems Analyst 3",
    "company_name": "System Optimzations",
    "home_phone": "555-555-5555",
    "work_phone": "555-555-5555",
    "cell_phone": "555-555-5555",
    "custom_fields": [],
    "created_date": "2017-11-06T05:23:20.000Z",
    "modified_date": "2017-11-06T05:23:20.000Z",
    "source_details": "Web Devloping"
}
```

Comment: after changing $data['prefix_name'] = "tone"; still this error was showing [{"error_key":"json.payload.empty","error_message":"JSON payload cannot be empty."}]

Comment: @ManvendraRajpurohit  use my complete code including Curl code also. And if one time contact added then it will not added again. Tha's why you are getting error may be. Try with some new data and use my complete code

Comment: Thank you sir It works for me now, If any error then I will let you know..

Comment: @ManvendraRajpurohit  glad to help you :):)

Comment: Hello sir are you there?